# Need help understanding the proof of correctness of deciphering algorithm in the original RSA paper.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography, totient-function

In the paper "A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystems" by R.L. Rivest, A. Shamir, and L. Adleman, they prove correctness of deciphering algorithm by following ways:

> Due to Euler and Fermat : for any integer (message) M which is
> relatively prime to n, M<sup>φ(n)</sup> ≡1 (mod n) . (3)
>
> Here φ(n) is the Euler totient function giving number of positive
> integers less than n which are relatively prime to n. For prime
> numbers p,
>
> φ(p) = p −1 .
>
> In our case, we have by elementary properties of the totient function
> [7]:
>
> φ(n) = φ(p) ·φ(q)
> = (p −1) ·(q −1) (4)
> = n −(p + q) + 1 .
>
> Since d is relatively prime to φ(n), it has a multiplicative inverse e
> in the ring of integers modulo φ(n): e ·d ≡1 (mod φ(n)).

> M<sup>e·d</sup> ≡ M<sup>k·φ(n)+1</sup> (mod n) (for some integer k). 7 From (3) we see
> that for all M such that p does not divide M
>
> M<sup>p−1</sup> ≡1 (mod p)
>
> and since (p −1) divides φ(n)
>
> M<sup>k·φ(n)+1</sup> ≡M (mod p).
>
> This is trivially true when M ≡ 0 (mod p), so that this equality
> actually holds for all M. Arguing similarly for q yields
>
> M<sup>k·φ(n)+1</sup> ≡M (mod q) .
>
> Together these last two equations imply that for all M,
>
> M<sup>e·d</sup> ≡M<sup>k·φ(n)+1</sup> ≡M (mod n). This implies (1) and
> (2) for all M,0 ≤ M < n. T. Therefor E and D are inverse permutations.

I do not understand the part where they do : M<sup>e·d</sup> ≡ M<sup>k·φ(n)+1</sup> (mod n) (for some integer k)
what does that mean? Is it because both e and d are less than φ(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ means that the integer $ed$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $\phi(n)$ so there is some integer $k$ so that $$e\cdot d  =k\cdot\phi(n)+1$$

(the $k$ is the integer quotient of $ed$ when divided by $\phi(n)$)

so that $$M^{e\cdot d} \equiv M^{k\phi(n) +1} \pmod{n}$$ then auromtically follows. The exponents are the same, hence the powers of $M$ too.

So it's just a reformulation of $d$ and $e$ being inverses modulo $\phi(n)$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I did not see that dupe in my right column otherwise I would have marked it as such. I quite rely on the site’s algorithms to surface them for me. Most of the times I rely on my memory to find them.